# Discord.py I'm getting this error when I try to send a custom prefix to a JSON file: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I am writing a discord.py bot, and I'm trying to make a command that allows servers to set their own prefixes. This is the code:

```
@bot.command(
    help = "Set the server prefix!"
)
async def setprefix(ctx, arg1):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'a+') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
        prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = arg1
    await ctx.channel.send(f"The server prefix has been set to **{arg1}**")
```

This is what the json file looks like:

```
{
    "guild_id": "!",
}
```

Here, "guild_id": "!" is just a placeholder for it to make sense.

When I run the command on my test server, this is the error that I get this full transcript:

```
Ignoring exception in command setprefix:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/secret/OneDrive/PyBot/Millenium_Build.py", line 174, in setprefix
    prefixes = json.load(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open('prefixes.json', 'a+') as f:
```

Opening with `a+` mode opens the file for *appending*, meaning the pointer starts at the end of the file. Therefore, there's nothing to read when you call `json.load(f)`.

```
        prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = arg1
```

This line here also has no effect at all. It won't write anything to the file, if that's what you're expecting to do.

Instead, you want to do something like this:

```py
    with open('prefixes.json') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = arg1
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f)
    ...
```

Ideally, you would want to make this an atomic action, but this will do for demonstration of solving the problem you have.

As an additional aside, a trailing comma in the json file will also cause a decode error (although it's not the error you're seeing here).